# Port forwarding not working for Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, portforwarding

I am running my Nodejs application on port 9000. I want the application to be accessible from a public IP address.

I went to my router config and did:

[image]

My Nodejs application is still running on localhost:9000 but when I go to

`mypublicipaddress:9000`

I get this site cannot be reached.

I also tried the netsh command:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9000 connectport=9000 connectaddress=192.168.1.12
```

This did not throw any error message but this also did not work.

Comment: Maybe the firewall of your PC or server is blocking it

Comment: I enabled port 9000 in my firewall through inbound rules but this did not help either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I went to my router config and did: [...]
>
> My Nodejs application is still running on localhost:9000

This implies that you've bound your Node.js server to your loopback interface on your machine and are trying to reach it from your router which is impossible. Try to bind the server to an IP address that is reachable by the router or bind it to all IP addresses on your local machine (ie. `0.0.0.0` or `::`).

For example:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => { res.end('It works') });
server.listen(9000, '0.0.0.0');
```

As for the netsh command, **I think** you should also set the `listenaddress` to your machine address on your network (or `0.0.0.0`). Also, `connectaddress` must be set to `127.0.0.1`:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9000 connectport=9000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 listenaddress=192.168.1.12
```

Comment: I am getting:

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:9000`. When I try to run my Nodejs server. I can however still run it in any other ports

Comment: `app.listen(9000,()=>{})` also works. Adding `0.0.0.0` gives the error above

Comment: You need to figure out what's listening on port 9000 and stop it. Also remove the netsh portproxy if you're going to bind the Node.js server to all IP addresses.

Comment: I changed the port to 8000 and am now doing `app.listen(8000,'0.0.0.0',()=>{})`. The server runs fine when i do `localhost:8000` but when I change it to `mypublicip:8000` it does not work anymore. I also enabled port forwarding for port 8000 like I did above for 9000 in my router

Comment: Also, I created an inbound rule for port 8000 in my firewall incase that was the problem but that did not solve the problem either.

Comment: At this point your problem is most likely not related to Node.js. Try to use a packet capturing tool like Wireshark to confirm your router is forwarding the traffic correctly to your machine. (Port forwarding is broken on some routers). Also you can run Wireshark and try to reach the server from another machine on the same network (to confirm that your firewall is not blocking the inbound traffic to your machine) Or you can just disable the firewall completely and see if it works.

Comment: This means I was not opening the port properly in my firewall I guess?